# Manipulating Lists in Haskell using Higher-Order Functions and Lambda Calculus

Tags: list, haskell, lambda, higher-order-functions

I am trying to write a very simple function that takes a list (for example : `[1,2,3,1,5]`) and returns a list of elements that are directly after a specific element.

What I have reached so far is:

```
function element list = filter (\x -> element:x) list
```

My desired output:

> function 1 [1,2,3,1,5]
>
> =>      [2,5]

Comment: By "next to", I assume you mean "after", correct?

Comment: exactly; The specified element direclty precedes the desired element

Comment: w/ list comprehensions this is `foo a xs = [y | (x:y:_) <- tails xs, x==a]`. [`tails` is from Data.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
map snd $ filter ((== x) . fst) $ zip theList (tail theList)
```

This won't work on an empty list, you will still need extra code to deal with that.

---

How does this work?

First, note that the values flow from right to left.  The `($)` operator allows this to happen.  So, the first part evaluated is the `zip` function.

```
zip theList (tail theList)
```

For your example above, this would yield

```
zip [1,2,3,1,5] [2,3,1,5]
```

equaling

```
[(1,2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (1,5)]
```

which is the set of concurrent pairs in the list.

Next, the filter is applied

```
filter ((== x) . fst) $ ....
```

In English, what this says is, filter out only the concurrent pairs whose first element equals `x`.  The output is

```
[(1,2), (1,5)]
```

Now we have the list of concurrent pairs starting with *1*.

Finally, we apply the map

```
map snd $ ....
```

This just pulls out the second value of the pair.

```
map snd [(1,2), (1,5)] = [2,5]
```

which is the desired value.

---

Note, my comment above about failing on the empty list.

This is because `tail` crashes on the empty list

```
tail [] --error
```

There are ways to patch this behavior (see the `safe` package, for instance), but it is mostly bookkeeping at this point, so I left that for you to work out.

---

Also note that since all of the functions we used are lazy, this approach would work for lists of infinite length as well.

Comment: just replace `tail` with `drop 1` and it'll work for empty lists too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily with a simple list comprehension, e.g.:

```
successors xs i = [y | (x,y) <- zip xs (drop 1 xs), x == i]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work to your specifications

```
next x (i:y:ys) -- look at the first two items in the list
    | x == i = -- if the first item == x, 
        y : next x (y:ys) -- take the second, and continue minus the first element
    |otherwise = -- not equal, 
        next x (y:ys) -- so skip that element
next _ [_] = [] -- if there's no second element, then stop
next _ _ = [] -- if the list is empty, stop
```